# Why does the fast pointer in loop detection of linked list need to be two steps ahead?

Tags: java, linked-list

Most of the solutions for detecting the loop in a linked list say that the fast pointer need to move twice the steps of the slow pointer. Why can't we have the fast pointer be just one step ahead and if `fast.next == slow` we are done.
The code would look something like this

```
slow = head;
fast = head.next;

while(fast.next != slow)
{
   slow = slow.next;
   fast = fast.next;
   if(fast == null) /* No loop to begin with, break */
       break;
}

return fast; /* The starting loop node*/
```

Edits: I meant fast.next != slow

Comment: Er, how would that detect cycles of larger length than, like, 2?

Comment: What does that mean? This approach might be naive but it should work. The fast is always one ahead. here fast and slow don't meet but slow.next must equal fast for a cycle.

Comment: Er, as it stands, `slow.next` is always equal to `fast` no matter whether there's a cycle or not.  Saying "the fast is always one ahead" is the same thing as saying "slow.next is equal to fast."

Comment: Your code is not working. At the first iteration "slow.next==fast" and then you detect "loop" of size of 1 (which isn't a loop at all). Generally you need to accelerate the fast pointer, so it'll get the first in case of any loop length. Additionally, please point to solution with two stops ahead...

Comment: Yes, I drew the diagram meaning slow.next should be equal to fast without realizing I started with the condition that fast.next should be equal to slow. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, because your pointers will never meet, since fast will always be one ahead of slow, and the pointers meeting is what you use to detect a cycle.

Also, if you do have loops, you will get into infinite loops. Let's say you have

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
     ^_________|
```

1. when slow is 1, fast is 2
2. when slow is 2, fast is 3
3. when slow is 3, fast is 4
4. when slow is 4, fast is 2
5. when slow is 2, fast is 3 (we've been here before, infinite loop)

Comment: Thanks got it! Don't know what I was thinking while posting this question here.